# Share the same private key on two ledger devices

Tags: private-key, ledger-hardware-wallet

I have 2 ledger device.

Let's suppose one for me and one for my wife.

We want to share the same bitcoin account.

Is it a good practice to setup the first ledger and then restore the keywords on the second ledger (while the first is still working) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Whether or not it is good practice depends on your threat model (I personally wouldn't for security reasons), but it is technically possible - the ledger devices and corresponding computer apps will have no issues with it.

Comment: Let's suppose i die in a accident. How my wife will take my bitcoins ?

Comment: Put the seed words in a safe that she has access to

Comment: A second ledger is more safe than a paper with ledger header. Isn’t it ? Is there a way ledger blacklist my device if they see the same private key on 2 devices ? (I will run ledger softwares)

Comment: @Bob5421 if your ledger device breaks somehow, your bitcoins will be lost forever. You should have a physical (ie non-digital) backup of some sort, in any case. There is otherwise no issue having two devices with the same keys.

Comment: Ledger does not care if you use one see on 100 devices, or on a ledger + trezor, or on a ledger + electrum. However, with each initial copy, you open yourself up to more attack vectors (each device will have a PIN, two devices offer 6 tries in total, 100 will offer 600). You should write it on a piece or paper, or get something like a crypto steel, and put it in a safe/vault that your wife (or the executor of your will/attorney) can access

Comment: @Bob5421 both devices can spend from that wallet so she can just use her's.